# Get last n files in directory sorted by timestamp without listing all files

Tags: linux, file, sorting, go, memory

I am trying to get get last `N` files from a directory sorted by Creation/Modification time.
I am currently using this code:

```
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    sort.Slice(files, func(i, j int) bool {
        return files[i].ModTime().Before(files[j].ModTime())
    })
```

The problem here is that the expected amount of files in this directory is ~ 2mil and when I get all of them in a slice, it consumes a lot of memory ~ 800mb. Also it is not sure when the GC will clean the memory.

Is there other way where I can get the last `N` files in the directory sorted by ts without reading and consuming all of the files in the memory?

Comment: Use [os.Readdir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) with `n > 0` instead.

Comment: But then how to get the oldest N files. The files should be sorted by ModTime before that

Comment: You'll need to do that yourself, just keep the oldest N files and keep reading the directory list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently listing files in a directory having very many entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513460/efficiently-listing-files-in-a-directory-having-very-many-entries)

Comment: The linked answer shows how to chunk up listing a very large directory. Keeping the older N is not something Go will do for you.

Comment: Hmmm but osReaddir just take a count `n`, not begin and start index for the files.
For example when I call it with count 10 and it returns the first 10 files in the directory, then how can I get the next 10 files

Comment: Per the [method comment](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir): `Subsequent calls on the same file will yield further FileInfos.` Just keep calling it until you get `io.EOF`.

Comment: Because as I understand, I have to create a slice with the desired filesCount: Slice of 1000 elements for example. Then i have to fetch the files by portions of 1000 elements and to update the main slice to contains only the oldest files

Comment: Hmm okay, this will improve the memory usage, thanks

Comment: Side note: on many (maybe even most) Linux file systems, it's unwise to put millions of files into a single directory. A bunch of file systems have O(n) or even O(n^2) behavior on directory entries.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer using `filepath.Walk` was still allocating a huge chunk of memory as @Marc pointed out. So here an improved algorithm.

Note: This is not an optimized algorithm. It's just about providing an idea on how takle the problem.

```golang
    maxFiles := 5
    batch := 100 // optimize to find good balance

    dir, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    var files []os.FileInfo
    for {
        fs, err := dir.Readdir(batch)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }
        for _, fileInfo := range fs {
            var lastFile os.FileInfo
            if maxFiles <= len(files) {
                lastFile = files[len(files)-1]
            }
            if lastFile != nil && fileInfo.ModTime().After(lastFile.ModTime()) {
                break
            }

            files = append(files, fileInfo)

            sort.Slice(files, func(i, j int) bool {
                return files[i].ModTime().Before(files[j].ModTime())
            })

            if maxFiles < len(files) {
                files = files[:maxFiles]
            }
            break
        }
    }
```

The basic idea is to only keep the oldest max X files in memory and discard the newer ones immediately or as soon as an older file pushes them out of the list.

---

Instead of a slice it might be helpful to look into using a btree (as it is sorted internally) or a double linked list. You'll have to do some benchmarking to figure out what is optimal.